# ssis package from SQL agent failed

Tags: ssis

I have simple package which reads data from csv file and loads into SQL table. File is located on another server and it is shared. I use UNC path in package. package is scheduled using sql agent job. Job worked fine for 1 week and suddenly started giving error "The file name "\\124.0.48.173\basel2\Commercial\Input\ACBS_GSU.csv" specified in the connection was not valid.  End Error  Error: 2010-04-20 16:15:07.19     Code: 0xC0202070     Source: ACBS_GSU Connection manager "CSV file conection"  Description: Connection "CSV file conection" failed validation."

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess the UNC path is invalid. Shouldn't it start with \\ here?

Comment: Sorry it was typo error.

Comment: What bothers me is when file is missing or path is wrong it used give error that file not found. But now it is failing at validation level only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe but after banging my head for whole day we restarted the server and it worked.
Now I know one thing for sure for any problem that seems to be irrational solution is Restart!

Comment: Same here. I couldn't get it executed successfully, after trying multiple things, then after a reboot it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like SMB connection timeout. Are you traversing a firewall to reach the target?